# How to split a string using : "\\" or "\"?

Tags: c, string

I have this string:
`char *path = " one\\\two\\\five\\\six";`

I want to separate it to an array when every cell is the string.
I'm using `strtok`, buy my problem is in calculating how much space to allocate for the array.

I'm doing that:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < strlen(path) ; i++)
{
   if (path[i] == '\'  && path[i+1] == '\') /*doesn't work! :( */
      counter++
}
```

the comparator line isn't working... I also tried writing : "\" but it doesn't work as well.
What is wrong?

editing 
I'm trying to use strtok and It get's messy :(

```
     char           seps[]      =   "\\";
     char           *elemName   =   NULL;

 elemName = strtok( path, seps );

 while( elemName != NULL )
     {
          /* While there are tokens in "string" */
         /*copy the elemName*/
         stringArr[runner] = strdup(elemName);
         /* Get next token: */
          elemName = strtok( NULL, seps );
     }
 printf("printing the strings!!!!\n");
 for ( i = 0 ; i < arr_size ; i++)
 {
     printf (" %s \n " , stringArr[i]);
 }
```

Comment: you escape the ' with the first \, I believe you must use if( path[i] == '\\' && path[i+1] == '\\' ). This is due the first \ tells the next \ to be used as a "sign" and not as a escaping symbol again. So in return \\ gives you a "\" letter to compare with.

Comment: I would also notice that on the last iteration you are out of bounds as path[i+1] would be attending to rubbish

Comment: I'm sorry didn't unserstand you ... path[i] is a char..can I use it's ascii ? like : char[i] == 92 && char[i+1]==92.. ? and how can I enter two chars when comparing ? :'\\' is two chars no?

Comment: @user1386966 no, `'\\'` is two `\ ` characters evaluated as one single `\ ` char.

Comment: @YardenEitan Actually, it will be the terminator character in `path[i + 1]` for the last character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are correct, but it would still be a redundant loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write `'\\'` (or numeric 92, as it's `\` ASCII value). `\` is an escape character, and if you want to have it included in string, you need to escape it on it's own.

explanation: `\(whatever)` is translated to one char in compilation phase. (for example, `\n` -> char with ASCII value 0x0A)

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to involve numerical ASCII values. Anyway, ASCII value for line feed (`'\n'`) is 10, not 0x10.

Comment: @unwind, it is, in my opinion, good for understanding how it works 'below'. however, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the `\` character in a string or character literal is the *escape* character (as explained in the answer by Yossarian), this means even if you have a string literal containing `\\` the compiler will convert it to a single `\` in the actual string.

So if you in your code have:

```
char *path = " one\\two\\five\\six"
```

If you print that out (with e.g. `printf`) you will see that it as:

```
one\two\five\six
```

This means your logic is wrong, and you don't have to check for *two* backslashes, it also means that you don't have to worry about reading beyond the string end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes : `'\\'` represents the backslash character `\`

Answer (score 0):

a string declared like this:

```
char * path = "one\\two"
```

has 7(+1) characters, 'o' 'n' 'e' '\' 't' 'w' 'o' ('\0'). That's because you have to escape the single backslash. So use just this:

```
if ( path[i] == '\\' ) {
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '\' to split split on the "\" as using single "\" will not work because "\" is a escape character.

Answer (score 0):

For your allocation problem:
You are only supposed to allocate memory for a NULL terminated array of pointers to strings.

So, loop through the string, and count the delimiters. You need to allocate 2 + the count. There is one more string then delimiters, and in addition one terminating  NULL pointer.

```
char **strv = malloc( (2 + count) * sizeof( char*) );
```

Next step is to loop though the string again, and set the pointers in the array you just allocated. Something like:

```
strv[ i++ ] = string;

for ( pstr = string; *pstr != '\0'; pstr++ ){
    if( *pstr == delimiter ) {
        *pstr = '\0';
        strv[ i++ ] = pstr + 1;
    }
}
strv[ i ] = NULL;
```

(Code modifies original string.)
Remember to free both the string and the allocated pointer array.

I assume '\\' is an escape character followed by the backslash. '\\' is hence just one character. Make sure the counting part of your code don't count it twice.

-Øystein